# journalctl follow is wrapping to the begginning

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

Can someone explain to me why on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 the journalctl -f command wraps around to the beginning?

e.g. Note the jump back to Feb 04 right where the `-- Reboot --` line appears.  Isn't follow mode meant to follow from the end?

```
matthewh@xen:~$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-04-18 17:57:48 NZST. --
Jun 08 09:29:04 xen unknown[19540]: hello
Jun 08 09:29:21 xen gnome-shell[3277]: clutter-actor.c:10049: Actor 'dashtodockDashScrollview' tried to allocate a size of 52.00 x -50.00
Jun 08 09:31:30 xen gnome-shell[3277]: clutter-actor.c:10049: Actor 'dashtodockDashScrollview' tried to allocate a size of 52.00 x -50.00
Jun 08 09:31:41 xen cat[19590]: hello2
-- Reboot --
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen systemd-journald[420]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 405.801ms for 1030 entries.
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: wmi: Mapper loaded
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: i5500_temp 0000:00:14.3: Sensor seems to be disabled
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000084F (\PMRG) (20150930/utaddress-254)
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000053F (\GPS0) (20150930/utaddress-254)
```

Other strange behavior is that follow mode with `--cursor=` option will work correctly for ~30s but then do the jump back in time once 30s is up or another entry is written to the journal in the mean time then it will jump back in time.  Is this a bug or a configuration issue or corruption of something?

Another strange behavior is if I vacuum to the last 1 hour it frees up lots of space but `journalctl -f` still shows historic journals.

e.g.

```
matthewh@xen:~$ sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1h
[sudo] password for matthewh: 
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/user-65534@66df57ade95c47cf9eac8bb3bad2fcd6-000000000028c69f-00056a41cbc84fd5.journal (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/user-1000@f74fb09ddbf942c48992ffeddad027aa-00000000002823a0-00056a19227c797c.journal (128.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/system@00056cd44e74370d-ec95fe61be96ccaa.journal~ (16.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/user-1000@00056d4b94c36b5c-43aaf4145d90c4ae.journal~ (72.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/system@00056d4a91984e48-9512cc0d6176403f.journal~ (24.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/system@00056d4bce11d451-eaa91647ccf83b07.journal~ (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/user-1000@00056d4bcf608ab9-215b647018a9035c.journal~ (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/system@00056d4be31c3eda-bcef2162c8c45fb7.journal~ (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/user-1000@00056d4bf4c04d3c-a35514c599bfbf45.journal~ (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/system@4e816c29657c4ac19594d7c4de14afd7-0000000000000001-00056d4be316a78f.journal (48.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d/user-1000@b7f2a0f19c9946abab26788729a244c5-00000000000008a0-00056d4bf4c029b5.journal (16.0M).
Vacuuming done, freed 344.0M of archived journals from /var/log/journal/f899a862e4aa4775b8995564d8da565d.

matthewh@xen:/var/log/journal$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-04-18 18:01:40 NZST. --
Jun 08 09:40:12 xen gnome-shell[3277]: clutter-actor.c:10049: Actor 'dashtodockDashScrollview' tried to allocate a size of 52.00 x -50.00
Jun 08 09:40:22 xen sudo[19775]: matthewh : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log/journal ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl --vacuum-time=10m
Jun 08 09:40:22 xen sudo[19775]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 08 09:40:22 xen sudo[19775]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
-- Reboot --
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen systemd-journald[420]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 405.801ms for 1030 entries.
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: wmi: Mapper loaded
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: i5500_temp 0000:00:14.3: Sensor seems to be disabled
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000084F (\PMRG) (20150930/utaddress-254)
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Feb 04 13:03:05 xen kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000053F (\GPS0) (20150930/utaddress-254)
```

It would seem that the journalctl program is reading those journals from somewhere, but maybe it thinks they are still current or in the future despite the date.  Could that be true?  where might it be reading them from?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there must have been some kind of corruption in `/var/log/journal` whereby `vacuum 10m` didn't even remove the old entries.

I'm not entirely sure how journalctl determines what constitutes a new log, but for some reason a log from Feb 04 was deemed current and so it would display it.

It had the side effect of not displaying current entries as they were written. i.e. follow wasn't working.  And from making cursors work.

So the fix was:

```
rm -rf /var/log/journal/*
systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
```

I didn't need to keep the old logs so a full delete was fine.